# Appending history of one git repository to another

Tags: git, git-merge

How can I tack the history of one git repository onto another?
I have two similar projects I'd like to merge the histories of.
They have diverged somewhat, but essentially the job they do is now the same, which is why I wanted to do this.

So essentially I'd like it to take it from this:

```
repo1/master 1a----1b---1c--1d
repo2/master 2a--2b--2c-----2d
```

to this:

```
repo1/master 1a----1b---1c--1d-2a--2b--2c-----2d
repo2/master 2a--2b--2c-----2d
```

I'm thinking either merge straight on, or clear files from one, so it's mergable and merge the other on top of my cleaned repository?

What's a sensible way to do this?

Cheers

Comment: Do the two branches have a common ancestor, and, if so, where is it in the diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a very good candidate for doing a `git rebase`, and here is how I would solve it:

```
git checkout repo2/master                   # step 1
git checkout -b repo2temp                   # step 2
git rebase repo1/master                     # step 3
git push origin repo2temp:repo1/master      # step 4
```

First, in steps #1 and #2, I create a new temporary branch called `repo2temp` based on the `repo2/master` branch.  Next, I rebase this temporary branch, which looks identical to `repo2/master`, on `repo1/master`.  After this step # the diagrams look like this:

```
repo1/master 1a----1b---1c--1d
repo2temp    1a----1b---1c--1d--2a--2b--2c-----2d
```

After step #4, once you have pushed the rebased `repo2temp` branch to the remote `repo1/master` branch, then the branches will look like the following:

```
repo1/master 1a----1b---1c--1d--2a--2b--2c-----2d
repo2temp    1a----1b---1c--1d--2a--2b--2c-----2d
repo2/master 2a--2b--2c-----2d
```

Comment: I think you can only rebase if there is a commit in common between the two repositories?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I thought editing things reset their vote status?

Comment: Anyway yes - there is no commit in common.